# Cannot Compose Email in Lightning

Tags: lightning, email

On a Standard or Custom object, I have added the email action to the page and can see the tab under the activity section of the page but when I click on Email I cannot compose the email.

Profile is system administrator, Deliverability is set to All email, Enhanced email is disabled.In user settings the email setting is set to send via Salesforce.

Does anyone have any idea about how to get it working?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. The issue was that the layout on the email global action was blank. Added the standard fields into the global action layout and resolved.